# Only one link opening in div with ajax refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a link as follows:

```
<a id="link" href="hospitaldetails.php?id=1">Click Here</a>
```

Clicking on link will update a div on same page using Ajax:

```
<!--Div containing ajax response of hospital details-->
<div id="container"></div>
```

The jQuery ajax script is as follows:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 //getting details of hospital through ajax request and displayed on <div> with id container
    $("#link").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // <-------stop the default behavior here.
      var id = this.href.split('=').pop(); // extract the id here
      $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "hospitaldetails.php",
        data: {id:id}, // now pass it here
        success: function(data) {
          $('#container').html(data);
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Everything is working fine except that on the page there are multiple links with different id's like:

```
href="hospitaldetails.php?id=1"
href="hospitaldetails.php?id=2"
```

clicking on first link will update the container div correctly, but the second link will open in a new window with url hospitaldetails.php?id=2.

Why is it not updating the same div with content from new id ?? What is wrong with the code above ??

Comment: Can you show an example of how you are setting up the second div? Are you using a div with the same id="link"? Assuming so, you need to make that a class as there should only be one element with a given ID on a page. I imagine changing it to a class and targeting the class should fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, it is div with same id "link". It is a loop and the details like hospital id is pulled from database.
<a id="link" href="hospitaldirections.php?id=1">Click Here</a>
<a id="link" href="hospitaldetails.php?id=2">Click Here</a>

Comment: Use clases, id need to be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your IDs are unique:

```
<a id="link1" href="hospitaldetails.php?id=1">Click Here</a>
<a id="link2" href="hospitaldetails.php?id=2">Click Here</a>
```

However, it's probably easier if you define a selector for the AJAX listener, instead. For example:

```
<a class="ajaxlink" href="hospitaldetails.php?id=1">Click Here</a>
```

And have your listener reference this selector:

```
$(".ajaxlink").click(function(e) {
```